# PostgreSQL, case when by row values

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-when

for each row of the dataset i need to make a assignment with some criterion.
so for example:

| id | ValA | ValB | ValC | Vald |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 11 | 1 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | NULL | 1 | 8 |
| 4 | NULL | 3 | 2 | NULL |

I need a new table like

| id | Typ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | D |

my idea was to make a case when statement in the select like:

```
case when ValA > ValB > "all other row values" then 'A'
     when ValD > ValA > "all other row values" then 'B'
     when ValA > ValD > "all other row values" then 'C' 
     else 'D'
end as Typ
```

Is there a way to assign something like this?

Comment: Huh?  Your criteria doesn't really make sense.  How are `NULL` values handled?

Answer (score 1):

The `NULL` values make this tricky.  But you seem to want to treat those as `0` or `-1`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when vala > valb and
                  valb > coalesce(valc, -1) and
                  valb > coalesce(vald, -1) 
             then 'A'
             when vald > vala and
                  vala > coalesce(valb, -1) and
                  vala > coalesce(valc, -1) 
             then 'B'
             when vala > vald and
                  vald > coalesce(valb, -1) and
                  vald > coalesce(valc, -1) 
             then 'C'
             else 'D'
       end) as typ
from t;
```

If you just wanted the highest value in a column (which makes more sense to me), then you can use a lateral join:

```
select t.*, v.typ
from t cross join lateral
     (select v.*
      from (values ('A', valA), ('B', valB), ('C', valC), ('D', valD)
           ) v(typ, val)
      where v.val is not null
      order by v.val desc
      limit 1
     );
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i need more than just the highest value, because the criterion can depend on more than one value. the second thing is, i have more than just 4 columns so is there a shorter way than to wrote every and in each when case?

Comment: @hahakomisch . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  For the bespoke logic you want to implement, it seems like a massive `case` expression is the only solution (at least given the information in the question).

Comment: is there another logic which solves the problem better? that was the only way which i could find to make a possible solution.